# Problem with mouse drag-lock in some apps

Tags: 18.04, mouse

Occasionally I have a problem in that the mouse (trackpad) decides to start a drag on a single click.

It mostly seems to affect QT applications (VirtualBox manager, KeepassXC, libreoffice calc -  can't recal whethre that's QT or GTK...) but also sometimes GTK apps like darktable.

The only way I can reset things seems to be to log out and in again.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Vanilla Gnome.

Is there an easier way to 'reset' things when this happens? It is disruptive to close everything down and log out/in again.

Comment: LibreOffice now uses gtk3. Earlier it used gtk2.